# Tool to detect memory leak in big C++ server application on AIX7.1 and AIX7.2

Tags: c++, memory-management, aix, db2

I am making an VC++/C++ application in AIX7.1.
Client system is made of VC++ and server is made of C++ and DB is Db2 v10.5.
Compiler version is following:
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V13.1.3 (5725-C72, 5765-J07)
Version: 13.01.0003.0005

Server will upgrade to AIX7.2 soon.

I would like to detect memory leak of server application. 
I used to use Purify but Purify did not work properly because the application is too big.

Could you tell me the best software to detect memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most famous memory debugger is [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). There's no [official indication](http://www.valgrind.org/info/platforms.html) that Valgrind supports AIX, but there are various people talking about running it on AIX:

- [AIX 5.3 - Valgrind 3.3.1](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/26936545/)
- [valgrind - pthread memory leaks on AIX](https://www.unix.com/aix/132867-valgrind-pthread-memory-leaks-aix.html)

Another solution suggested by IBM is [Debug malloc tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/debug_malloc.htm)

See also

- [Memory leak tool on AIX5.3 and 6.1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014552129)
- [Isolate and resolve memory leaks using `MALLOCDEBUG` on AIX Version 5.3](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-mallocdebug.html)
- [Tools to determine memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5195220/995714)
- [Is There a Tool to Check Memory Leaks On AIX Like Valgrind](https://it.toolbox.com/question/is-there-a-tool-to-check-memory-leaks-on-aix-like-valgrind-090514)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If Valgrind supported AIX officially, I would use it. But I cannnot use it in case of no official support. And Debug malloc tool is too simple for me.